# submitting paypal request - blank return screen

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I't my first time at creating a paypal payment request.  I am trying to set up a payment of a book. The book details such as price are taken from the data stored about the book in the database.  User just inputs the book ID. Ideally these details are turned into a paypal payment.

When I submit the form however, I just get a blank screen returned. Ideally I'd like the payment to be set up, then the user can confirm the purchase on the website.  Can anyone help me with trying to eliminate the blank screen?

The Code:

```
try {
      $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_USERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
} catch   (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}


  $book =$_GET["book_id"];
  $user =$_GET["user"];


$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title, price FROM books2 WHERE b_id=$book");
$sth->bindParam(':title', $title);
$sth->bindParam(':price', $price);
$sth->execute();




$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");


$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName($title)
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice($price);



$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping(1.2)
 ->setTax(1.3)
 ->setSubtotal(17.50);




$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($price)
    ->setItemList($item1)
    ->setDescription("Payment description")
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());



$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
    ->setPayer($user)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));

    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);


$request = clone $payment;


try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    ResultPrinter::printError("Created Payment Using PayPal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", null, $request, $ex);
    exit(1);
}


$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();

ResultPrinter::printResult("Setting up payment using Paypal. Please visit the URL to Approve.", "Payment", "<a href='$approvalUrl' >$approvalUrl</a>", $request, $payment);

return $payment;
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your code ?

Comment: I didn't have it no...I get the following error when adding error reporting.  `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Id cannot be null' `

Comment: That looks like a legitimate error. You might want to look more into it. Also try to see what part of your code is causing that error.

Comment: The error lies in the the prepared SELECT statement. 
`$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT title, price FROM books2 WHERE b_id=$book");` not sure why though. The items I am trying to select are not null

Comment: what is the value of `$book` that you are passing ?

Comment: This is not correct :`$sth->bindParam(':title', $title);
$sth->bindParam(':price', $price);` There is nothing to bind here since you are not specifying `:title`, `:price` in your query statement. Try removing those 2 lines and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Look at the syntax here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 0):

After you get the $approvalUrl you need to 
redirect them to the PayPal url. It would
look something like this.

```
$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();  
if(isset($approvalUrl)) {
    header("Location: $approvalUrl");
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove these lines from the code. You are trying to execute a payment first, which is not right.

```
$execution = new PaymentExecution();
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
```

Here is how the flow for paypal is:

1. Create a Payment using $payment->create() method.
2. Get the approval_url by following the steps provided by Ken Johnson.
3. User will complete the checkout by following the web browser and accept the payment.
4. You will be redirected back to your set "redirect_url".
5. You do a GET on PaymentId returned from the url $_GET[] array
6. Execute the payment using the below code.

You could follow the instructions provided here to get the full idea:
http://localhost/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/index.php#0adf233ad486604d0b6df90c586fbdad

Also, you may want to return these two lines, as they are just for sample purpose, and will throw Class not found exceptions.

```
ResultPrinter::printError(
ResultPrinter::printResult(
```